# How to get respective value to each value?

Tags: sql, oracle

Having Table like below

```
Main_mem    Neighnour_mem
---------------------------
101           -
102           -
103          102
104           -
105           -
106          105
107           -
108           -
109          108
110          108
```

I Need Output as below

```
Main_mem    Neighnour_mem
---------------------------
101             -
102            103
104             -
105            106
107             -
108            109
108            110
```

I tried below query, but wont work

```
SELECT A.Main_mem "Main_Member"
      , (SELECT Main_mem "Dependent_member" FROM family
          WHERE neigh_mem = A.Main_mem)"Dependent_member"
FROM family A
```

How to get my output?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess rules that lead from A to B? Why do you have 101 in desired output, but don't have 103?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self-`left join` and `not exists`:

```
select  
    f.main_mem,
    coalesce(f1.main_mem, f.neighnour_mem) neighnour_mem
from family f
left join family f1 on f1.neighnour_mem = f.main_mem
where not exists (select 1 from family f2 where f2.main_mem = f.neighnour_mem)
order by 1, 2
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=908096bc8565dae621cb6ea57634e619)**:

```
MAIN_MEM | NEIGHNOUR_MEM
:------- | :------------
101      | -            
102      | 103          
104      | -            
105      | 106          
107      | -            
108      | 109          
108      | 110
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the `Neighnour_mem` that are not `NULL` and then the `Main_mem` that have no matches at all:

```
select Neighnour_mem, Main_mem
from family f
where Neighnour_mem is not null 
union all
select f.Main_mem, null
from f
where not exists (select 1
                  from family f2
                  where f2.Neighnour_mem is not null and
                        f.Main_mem in (f2.main_mem, f2.Neighnour_mem)
                 );
```